# Array dropping values, picks up garbage

Tags: c, arrays, struct, gdb, garbage

After putting values into my array, one step later (thanks gdp) the array contains garbage.  The only step afterwards is passing parameters to a function:

```
struct Vertex;
typedef struct Vertex Vertex;
struct Vertex {
    int sides[2][LENGTH];
    int ends[2];
    Vertex *children;
    Vertex *parent;
};

void move(Vertex *node, int side, int place) {
(38) int handfull = (*node).sides[side][place];
.....
}

int blah(Vertex *node, int side) {
.....
(103)    *((*node).children + i) = init_child(node);
(104)    move((*node).children + i, side, i);
(105)    blah((*node).children + i, opposingside);
.....
}
```

gdb tells me the following:

```
(gdb) print (*node)
$7 = {sides = {{5, 5}, {0, 5}}, ends = {0, 1}, 
children = 0x7fffffffdfa0, parent = 0x7fffffffe110}
(gdb) print node
$8 = (Vertex *) 0x7fffffffe0c0
(gdb) print ((*node).children + i)
$9 = (Vertex *) 0x7fffffffdfa0
(gdb) print *((*node).children + i)
$10 = {sides = {{5, 5}, {0, 5}}, ends = {0, 1}, 
children = 0x7fffffffdf20, parent = 0x7fffffffe0c0}
(gdb) step
    move (node=0x7fffffffdfa0, place=0, side=0) at mancala.c:38
    38 int handfull = (*node).sides[side][place];
(gdb) print node
$11 = (Vertex *) 0x7fffffffdfa0
(gdb) print (*node)
$12 = {sides = {{-8160, 32767}, {4196818, 0}}, ends = {0, 1}, 
children = 0x7fffffffdf20, parent = 0x7fffffffe0c0}
```

I break at line 104 (called `move`).  After, `(*node).children + i` points to a Vertex structure as evidenced by $9 and $10.  I make one step into the `move` function.  This should push my Vertex address, the return address, etc. onto the stack and start working in the `move` function.  Looking at $11, we see that the Vertex address is the same as in $9, which is fine. However, in $12, the array `.sides` is now full of garbage.  Everything else is fine, but just that array is full of trash.

How has this happened in one step? I can't debug any further than one step at a time, so I don't know what to do now.

---

**EDIT:** Here's the init_child function:

```
Vertex init_child(Vertex *node) {
    Vertex children[LENGTH];
    int i;
    int j;
    Vertex child = (*node);
    for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        for (i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++)
            child.sides[j][i] = (*node).sides[j][i];
        child.ends[j] = (*node).ends[j];
    }
    child.children = children;
    child.parent = node;
    return child;
}
```

And here is the main() function that initializes the first Vertex:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Vertex children[LENGTH];
    Vertex head = {.sides = {{4,4}, {4,4}}, .ends = {0}, .children = children, .parent = NULL};
    blah(&head, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your full code please?  Or a cut-down example that still demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that `init_child()` is initializing `children` with the address of an array that was created at function scope. When the function returns, the array is no longer valid, and so the child structure returned is pointing to an invalid object.

```
Vertex init_child(Vertex *node) {
Vertex children[LENGTH];            /* array variable on the stack */
/*...*/
child.children = children;          /* child pointing to local variable */
child.parent = node;
return child;
}
```

Instead, the routine should dynamically allocate the memory so that the child points to memory with a lifespan that continues to survive after the function returns.

```
Vertex init_child(Vertex *node) {
/*...*/
child.children = malloc(LENGTH*sizeof(*child.children));
child.parent = node;
return child;
}
```

Comment: THANKS! This solved it.  I would up-vote, but I don't have enough rep, apparently.  <3 <3

Comment: I actually created space before calling init_child and passed that stuff to init_child:

Comment: That's find too, but if `LENGTH` is large or if `Vertex` is large, you risk exceeding the amount of memory the OS provided for the stack.